# How to install older JDK on OS X Yosemite?

Tags: java, macos

I'm following a netbeans tutorial that requires JDK 6.  My Mac came with version 1.8. Is there a way to revert back to an older JDK?  I've tried the oracle page, but there were no downloads for Mac.

Comment: There is no JDK 6.8, official Java 7 support ends at the end of this month. Also, sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Do you mean netbeans 6.8?

Comment: You can download Java 6 for Mac OS X [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US).

Comment: Sorry, I meant JDK 6.  I'm downloading it to be used with netbeans 6.8.  I've tried the oracle page, but couldn't find a mac download.  I also tried the apple developer page, and found a download for it, but it can only be installed on older operating systems.

Comment: NetBeans 6.8 is extremely old (as is Java6). You should really use up-to-date versions of Java and the IDE (which would be Java 8 and NetBeans 8.0). I'm pretty sure that tutorial will also work with current versions

Comment: @yole Thanks for that link, I've downloaded it and found where it is installed, what changes do I have to make to use this version?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use NetBeans and don't know how to configure the JDK version that it uses.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've been going through the tutorial with the newer versions of Java and Netbeans, but I've been experiencing issues lately that I think have to do with using newer versions.

Comment: If you're learning to program, it's _far_ more useful to understand the issues that you're experiencing (for example, by asking here on SO) than to try to evade them by blindly trying to match the environment of the tutorial as closely as possible.